# For JSON schemas, can the "type" keyword be missing if "pattern" keyword is set?

Tags: json, validation, types

For JSON schemas, can you have the keyword "pattern" set but not have the keyword "type" set to anything? Concern is whether I need to correct existing schemas that do this like the following:

```
"ExampleType": {
   "description": "blah blah",
   "type": "array",
   "items": {
      "pattern": "sometext/ExampleType:[^:/]+:[0-9]*$"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked this here [JSON validator](https://json-schema-validator.herokuapp.com/) and it can work however this would allow any non-string value so it will not care if a non-string value matches the pattern or not. For instance, you could have

```
{
"ExampleType" : ["sometext/ExampleType:try:1", "sometext/ExampleType:try:2", 5]
}
```

and it would pass. If the number 5 is put in quotes, then it would fail. So bottom line is that you should always specify the type and it will default to any type if not specified.